# Redis - Do I need to have sentinel when clustering is there?

Tags: redis

I have a working Redis sentinel setup already (master, slave and 3 sentinels). I am planning to set up a redis cluster with 3 masters & 3 slaves.

Can I get rid of sentinel set up when I have redis clustering? If not how would the set up look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **don't** need Sentinel when using Redis cluster.

Redis Cluster perform automatic failover if any problem happens to any master instance.

From [Redis Essentials](https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=08WGCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA170&lpg=PA170&dq=perform+automatic+failover+if+any+problem+happens+to+any+master+instance&source=bl&ots=C8DkbQYfo5&sig=kwQseIAPMpM6cDzxNcX4c_FWcps&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI4tfCld73yAIVgRs-Ch3zlwzM#v=onepage&q=perform%20automatic%20failover%20if%20any%20problem%20happens%20to%20any%20master%20instance&f=false) book:

> Redis Sentinel and Redis Cluster share a lot of characteristics, but
>   each has its own goal. Sentinel's goal is to provide reliable
>   automatic failover in a master/slave topology without sharding data.
>   Cluster's goal is to distribute data across different Redis instances
>   and perform automatic failover if any problem happens to any master
>   instance.